# in struts2 adding property files

Tags: struts2

I have been learning struts2 by referring tutorialspoint.com as of yesterday it was fine  but today i came across one problem.

I am doing internalization so they asked me to create property files and put it in classpath.

I created property files by right clicking on the src and then click the new and then I typed property so I clicked that then I created property file.

I am confused where I need to put it, they told me to put it in classpath but I dont know where that is.

Comment: classpath is the list of places the code is situated. Why do you need to put it on classpath?

Comment: Because S2 I18N files go on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put these properties files in root folder i.e. **src folder** , because struts2 will by default try to find properties file from root. I have attached a snippets of a working project where properties has been already kept in class-path.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the reply @arvin_codeHunk, Roman, Dave. it meant lot to me...